# MOSS 2007: BDC permisson problem - no BDC application is listed in the web part's configuration menu

Tags: sharepoint, moss, bdc

I'm actually working at MOSS 2007 project where I have to import data from an external data source (WebService) via an application in the Business Data Catalog. The application definition was created with BDC Meta Man and was imported successfully into the Business Data Catalog without any errors.

I've first tested the external data source through the option "Edit profile page template" where a BDC-Webpart is already located on a site. In the preferences menu of the web part I could selected the new BDC application with the "Typ"-Picker and everything works fine.

Unfortunately it doesn't work with BDC web parts on other MOSS applications which uses the same SSP. Every time I placed a BDC web part on a site and try to configure it. The "Typ"-Picker in the web part's menu remains empty and no application from BDC is listed.

I then checked the permission settings in the BDC menu of the SSP where I experimentally granted all rights to every user account so I could see if it was permission problem. Unfortunately it didn't change anything and the BDC application is still not visible in the "Typ"-Picker.

So perhaps someone had a similar problem and know what the problem is!

Bye,
Flo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set the permissions on the application as well as the entity.